# Cant get auto login Java to work

Tags: javascript, authentication

So I have an input button that I cannot seem to get to work when applying javascript. It is for an autologin which i have the fields auto populate now but i just need the button to automatically click.

```
<div id='loginBtnArea' style='align:right'>
                                        <input class="loginBtn" type="button" 
                                            value='Auto' 
                                            name="okbtn" 
                                            onmouseover="javascript: if (this.disabled==0) this.className='loginBtnHov'"
                                            onmouseout="javascript: if (this.disabled==0) this.className='loginBtn'"
                                            onClick="onSubmitForm()">       
                                    </div>
```

Comment: You should use `:hover` instead of your Javascript.

Comment: how would that work?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:hover

Answer (score 0):

Why you don't create a js function and call it with the element actions...?

**An example:**

```js
function changeClass(id, class_n){
  document.getElementById(id).className = class_n;
  // if(bla bla bla...){
  //document.theForm.submit();
  //} 
}
```

```html
<div id='loginBtnArea' style='align:right'>
  <input id = "Auto-BT" class="loginBtn" type="button" value='Auto' name="okbtn" onClick="changeClass('Auto-BT', 'loginBT');"> </div>
```